# AD Distribution Group Add User UnathorizedAccessException

Tags: c#, active-directory, exchange-server

I have a Universal Distribution group in AD. In Exchange I set up the group to be public so that any user can add or remove themselves from the group.

In C# I have the following code:

```
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "Domain.com");
GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, groupName);
UserPrincipal userP = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, User.Identity.Name);
group.Members.Add(userP);
group.Save();
```

The `group.Save();` causes a `UnathorizedAccessException`.

What setting do I have to change to allow any user to preform this action?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out you have to give make a change on the Security tab within AD. You have to give the appropriate people (or Domain Users if you want everyone) the proper rights under that tab.